# Running Intel GPU tools with Nvidia driver

Tags: graphics, driver, intel, nvidia, meson-build

I'm trying to run Intel GPU tests (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/igt-gpu-tools) with Nvidia drm but I get the bellow error: igt_kmod-WARNING: Could not load i915
Test requirement not met in function drm_open_driver, file ../lib/drmtest.c:566:
Test requirement: !(fd<0)
No known gpu found for chipset flags 0x4294967291 (any)
Last errno: 2, No such file or directory
I guess I need to specify the driver name in meson.build
Can anyone tell how to run the tests with it.